# Is it safe to use artifact that has vulnerability on test dependency?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm trying to use artifact that is on mvnrepository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4

As you can see [test dependencies], JUnit 4.12 has a vulnerability and has red warning sign.

I've downloaded this artifact via Gradle and inspected the external library. I found that pom.xml on commons-collections4 has test dependency for JUnit 4.12 actually.

Is it safe to use an artifact that has vulnerability on test dependency?

Comment: I removed your secondary question, as you should restrict your questions to one question per question.

Comment: sry, i apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you see "red warning sign" just because `commons-collections` exposes to much information about their build process when publishing artifacts
2. it is not a good idea to check dependencies manually, [OWASP](https://owasp.org/) developed a nice plugin for both [gradle](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/index.html) and [maven](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/) - do not waste your time on manual checks

Comment: thx a lot, for me as beginner, it helps really

Comment: Sorry but the part `exposes to much information about their build process when publishing artifacts` is simply wrong. The marker is there because it is related to the dependency Junit...

Comment: @khmarbaise if they were using flatten plugin information about test dependencies were never being exposed just because it is irrelevant for consumers, and I do believe you know about [thoughts that concept of single pom has some drawbacks](https://www.javaadvent.com/2021/12/from-maven-3-to-maven-5.html).

Comment: and yes, sharing single pom across classifiers (and assuming that different classifiers have same dependencies) seems to be wrong as well: in this particular case the "vulnerable artifact" is `commons-collections4-4.4-tests.jar` but not `commons-collections4-4.4.jar`